# Trigger a GraphQL mutation not using the Mutation component

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to send a mutation query to a GraphQL server that uses Apollo.

However, I only see the only way to achieve this is by using a Mutation component.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations/#the-mutation-component

Is there an easy way I can send mutations doing something like this?

import gql from 'graphql-tag';

```
client.query({
  query: gql`
    query TodoApp {
      todos {
        id
        text
        completed
      }
    }
  `,
})
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the mutation component to trigger a mutation.

You can just pass the mutation in the `gql` query object, something like:

```
client.query({
  query: gql`
    mutation MyMutation {
      doSomthing {
        id
        returnedValue1
      }
    }
  `,
})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```